# arch linux install: lspci call hangs

Tags: networking, installation, arch-linux

I am attempting to dual-boot Arch Linux (archlinux-2018.02.01-x86_64.iso & archlinux-2018.03.01-x86_64.iso) on a machine ([ASUS B071ZL3996](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834234645)) that has Windows pre-installed. I have been battling the lack of a network connection throughout the install (I can connect via wired and wireless connections on the Windows side).  While troubleshooting, I tried to inspect the network card with `lspci`.  Each time I call it, however, it hangs the install.  Specifically, it returns the following error:

`xhci host controller not responding, assume dead`

I am not quite sure what to make of this, since it seems to be related to USB errors (based upon what I have seen), but it only occurs for `lspci` calls.  Anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 7):

Try blacklisting nouveau before booting; it's the death of any install on laptops that use an NVIDIA Optimus setup, which this looks like it might be.

Hit `e` before choosing Arch from the ISO boot menu and add `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` to the kernel parameters.

Comment: was this the solution?